# Interpreting 3-vertex Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

What does the following Feynman diagram represent?

[image]

Comment: This is not a typical Feynman diagram. Usually it would be difficult to maintain momentum and energy conservation with just one three-point vertex. The blob must represent some resummation over Feynman diagrams to all orders. That must somehow give a vertex rule that can maintain momentum and energy conservation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this represents the initial state of a scattering process involving three scalar fields ($\varphi_a$, $\varphi_b$, and $\varphi_c$) and is a vertex in a larger Feynman diagram

The three in-pointing arrows represent the momenta of these scalar fields ($p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$) all entering the interaction.

The circle represents the interaction vertex. The $\Gamma$ represents the interaction strength between the fields.

---

If you're interested, I found the [TikZ code](https://tikz.net/feynman-3/) for this diagram.